# Highlight part of a table row

Tags: css

I have a table which has rows that alternate colors, when I hover over rows they are highlighted yellow.

I would like some of the rows to be highlighted all the time too(not just onhover). I have discovered however that most of the rows that are to be highlighted are right next to each other and it gives the effect that that part of the table is just yellow and it doesn't look that good.

I want to know if it is possible to create a small strip of highlighting through the middle of the row while the outsides remain their natural color.

This is what I have:

```
.resultTable tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1){
    background-color:white;
}
.resultTable tbody tr:nth-child(2n){
    background-color:#E6EBEC;
}

.resultTable tbody tr:nth-child(n):hover{
    background-color: yellow;
}

.highlightedRow{
    background-color:#F2F18D !important;
}
```

This is what I want:
[image]

UPDATE:

I cant seem to get the border method to work.

This is the closest I get but there is space between the borders.

```
.resultTable{
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.resultTable thead{
    background-color: #000099;
    color: white;
    font-size:22px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.resultTable caption{
    background-color: #000099;
    color: white;
    font-size:22px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.resultTable tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1){
    background-color:white;
    border-top:2px solid green;
    border-bottom:2px solid green;
}
.resultTable tbody tr:nth-child(2n){
    background-color:#E6EBEC;
    border-top:2px solid red;
    border-bottom:2px solid red;
}
.resultTable td{
    border:inherit;
}
.resultTable tbody tr:nth-child(n):hover{
    background-color: yellow  !important;
}

.highlightedRow{
    background-color:#F2F18D !important;
}
```

Gives me:
[image]

By the way: i made them red and green on purpose to easily spot the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `border-width: 3px;` or something and then set `border-color: #FFF;` that will do what you want.

In other words, you can't set part of a row to a color, unless you use an image for the background. But you can color the borders.

Comment: What about margin-top and margin-bottom?

Comment: I think `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` would show the color of the table background.  so that could work too.

Comment: I am getting a strange effect with putting borders on the rows. It seems to only make one border and not two between rows. It merges the bottom border from the top row and the top border from the bottom row. And alternates which color it uses.

Comment: Ok, that was due to a border-collapse further up I think but when I remove it none of the borders have colors now.

Comment: have you set your border color?  what about your border-width?

Answer (score 1):

Why not add a border to your highlighted row ?

```
.resultTable tbody tr:nth-child(n):hover{
    background-color: yellow;
    border-top: solid 1px #333;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #333;
}
```